# Check if name from one dataframe exists in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, data-science

I am new in python and here I want some help please help me.
I have two data frame one is containing the brand name and another is product name .here I want to filter the data from data frame two only for the given brand list in dataframe2.

```
**brand_Name:
filter_value
0   Xiaomi
1   Celkon
2   Gionee
3   Asus
4   iBall
5   Karbonn
6   Lava
7   Lenovo
8   Micromax
9   Panasonic**

**New:**
****source_product_name source_product_id   Status****
10  Redmi Y2 (Black, 32 GB) MOBFAANUCBGSRADJ    New
18  Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1 (Black, 64 GB)  MOBF4UQ9NSFFMH7Z    New
21  Honor 9 Lite (Glacier Grey, 64 GB)  MOBFF5ZGFJB78ZDB    New
26  Redmi Y2 (Black, 32 GB) MOBFAANUCBGSRADJ    New
34  Realme 3 (Radiant Blue, 32 GB)  MOBFE68WHF6MZKG5    New
36  Realme 3 (Radiant Blue, 64 GB)  MOBFE68WMCYD5SRT    New
40  Honor 7A (Gold, 32 GB)  MOBF3T87G3JWH667    New
41  Redmi Note 7 (Sapphire Blue, 32 GB) MOBFDXZ3TVHJFD8E    New
46  Honor 9 Lite (Glacier Grey, 64 GB)  MOBFF5ZGFJB78ZDB    New
50  Redmi 6 (Blue, 32 GB)   MOBF96CPQBJJHBGN    New
57  Honor 10 Lite (Sapphire Blue, 32 GB)    MOBFEMY3UZZUND2Z    New
58  Redmi Y2 (Gold, 64 GB)  MOBF7Y2DKUBEDUWH    New
59  Vivo V9 Pro (Black, 64 GB)  MOBFAFZZUHCXRFCF    New
60  Panasonic Eluga Ray 530 (Blue, 32 GB)   MOBFCMTFWGMSUA4H    New
61  Redmi Note 5 Pro (Red, 64 GB)   MOBF9JQUXSHWPFHC    New
72  Honor 10 Lite (Sapphire Blue, 64 GB)    MOBFCG2TH5GMGC26    New
75  Redmi 6A (Rose Gold, 32 GB) MOBFAMZB7HFYJUFX    New
76  Redmi 6A (Rose Gold, 16 GB) MOBF9N2YPNCX2CP7    New
77  Nokia 5.1 Plus (Black, 64 GB)   MOBFE3DUMGFKKHGR    Ne
```

These are the things that I have already tried
`A = brandName.loc[brandName.filter_value.isin(New['source_product_id'])]`

Here I am getting an empty data frame
`New.assign(InbrandName=New.source_product_id.isin(brandName.filter_value).astype(int))`

Here also only zero for all product name

```
New['status2'] = [
    'donot keep' if brandName['filter_value'] not in 
    New['source_product_name'].tolist() else 'keep' 
    for brandName['filter_value'] in New['source_product_name']
    ]
abcd=New[New['status2']=='keep']
```

Here I am also trying to print one extra column(keep/do not keep) if a source_product_name contains a particular brand.

Comment: what is your data ?

Comment: Hi,@Wen-Ben......Here I have two data frame 1 is containing brand name and  dataframe2 contains product name so I want to filter out source product name on the basis of given brand name....Please help me

Comment: isin here will not work ,that is partial match

Comment: @Wen-Ben Let's say if brand Redmi is there in source_product name then filter all source_product_name containing Redmi

Comment: check my answer .

Comment: @Wen-Ben Thank You So much for help......It is working for me

Comment: Yw :-) happy codiong